# How to make radial corners in `clip-path` look clean?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to make a login form with an unusual shape, but I’m struggling with the `border-radius` on a `<div>` with a `clip-path`.

This is the CSS I used on a `<div>`:

```css
background: red;
height: 80%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
border-radius: 5em;
```

It currently looks like this:

[image: Picture showcasing the problem.]

As you can see, the `border-radius` in the upper-left and lower-right corners are cut off. Is there a workaround to make this clean?

Instead of the corners being cut off I'd like them to be as shown in the image below.

[image: Picture showcasing the desired result.]

Comment: @PeterB I'm sorry, I just added the CSS I use on a div.

Comment: @Xufox I added a picture showcasing the desired result, I hope it's clear to understand. Thanks for improving this post

Comment: Looks like you'll need to make the `clip-path` a lot more detailed (to have dozens or even hundreds of points very close to each other).

Comment: I'd be thinking of an SVG for this, Pretty sure it would be too involved for a CSS clip-path. Polygons don't have curves as such...just sides.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.block {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This article is helpful: dev.to/afif/css-shapes-with-rounded-corners-56h

Your example:

```css
.block {
  display:inline-block;
  width:460px;
  height: 500px;
  color:red;
  margin:20px;
  filter:url(#round);
  backgroudn: red;
}
.block::before {
   content:"";
   display:block;
   padding-top:100%;
   background: red;
 
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="round">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

If you want to change the value of radial corners then change the attribute `stdDeviation` in SVG tag.

The solution has one problem is to display incorrect for IOS

I suggest you to use SVG for similar geometry